# Can group name variable be dynamic in azure pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, pipeline, devops, azure-pipelines

I have two environments on azure. One difference between them is only environment variables that came from variable groups. Is it possible to set up group name dynamically for one pipeline instead of set up two pipelines that can map their own group variables?
It is an example of my build pipeline

```
trigger:
  - master
  - develop


jobs:

- job: DefineVariableGroups
   steps:
    - script: |
      if [ $(Build.SourceBranch) = 'refs/heads/master' ]; then
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=group_name_variable;isOutput=true]beta_group"
      elif [ $(Build.SourceBranch) = 'refs/heads/develop' ]; then
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=group_name_variable;isOutput=true]alpha_group"
      fi
    name: 'DefineVariableGroupsTask'
  - script: echo $(DefineVariableGroupsTask.group_name_variable)
    name: echovar # that works.

- job: Test
  dependsOn: DefineVariableGroups
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
  variables:
    - group: $[ dependencies.DefineVariableGroups.outputs['DefineVariableGroupsTask.group_name_variable'] ]
    # that doesn't work. Error here
steps:
  - script: echo $(mode)
    displayName: 'test'
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Each environment can have a different variable group associated with it. Is this a build pipeline or a release pipeline?

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. It's a build pipeline. What I want is to have one build pipeline similar to the above one. But I want also to make it run with a specific variable group which can be calculated depends on the branch name

Comment: @alexche8, Could you please share the complete YAML file, I could not reproduce your problem with current YAML, it always throw the error "there were validation errors or warnings,..Mapping values are not allowed in this context." for the line `name: 'DefineVariableGroupsTask'`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach or workaround that you can use is with templates.
I'm sure that the best option is the possibility to use "group variable" dynamically, while it isn't possible I believe that this is one option.

```
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - develop
    - qa
    - production

variables:
- name: defaultVar
  value:  'value define yml on project repo'
- group: variables-example-outside


resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: yml_reference
      type: github
      ref: refs/heads/yml_reference
      name: enamba/azure_devops
      endpoint: enamba

jobs:
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/develop') }}: 
  - template: deploy.example.yml@yml_reference
    parameters:
      GroupVariablesName: variables-example-developer

- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/qa') }}: 
  - template: deploy.example.yml@yml_reference
    parameters:
      GroupVariablesName: variables-example-qa

- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/production') }}: 
  - template: deploy.example.yml@yml_reference
    parameters:
      GroupVariablesName: variables-example-production
```

Inside of template:

```
parameters:
  GroupVariablesName: ''

jobs:
- job: deploy_app
  displayName: 'Deploy application'
  variables:
  - group: ${{ parameters.GroupVariablesName }}
  - group: variables-example-inside

  steps:
    - script: |
        echo outsidevar '$(outsidevar)'
        echo defaultVar '$(defaultVar)'
        echo var by tag '$(variable)'
```

Answer (score 3):

> Can group name variable be dynamic in azure pipelines?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid this is not supported at this moment. So we have to declare the variable group you want to consume in a YAML pipeline.

Some other communities raised the same requirement earlier, and this requirement has been passed to product team, you can check the details from the ticket:

Ticket: [Dynamic Variable Groups?](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3702)

Note: You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I subscribed on the issue to track it.

Answer (score 2):

for ones who is looking into it (found here https://www.eliostruyf.com/quick-tip-dynamic-variable-groups-azure-devops-yaml-pipelines/):

```
variables:
- ${{ if eq(variables['build.SourceBranchName'], 'refs/tags/develop') }}:
  - group: variables_group_master
- ${{ if ne(variables['build.SourceBranchName'], 'refs/tags/master') }}:
  - group: variables_group_dev
```

Please be careful about the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use runtime parameters within the pipeline to dynamically reference group names without the need to have them hardcoded in the yaml itself.

A very basic example

```
parameters:
- name: env
  type: string
  default: dev

variables:
- group: my-group-name-${{ parameters.env }}
```

so without passing any parameters, the variable group used will be

```
my-group-name-dev
```

but perhaps you pass in a parameter to your yaml file, e.g. qa

```
my-group-name-qa
```

will be the variable group used.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar situation and thought I would share my results.

While in theory you can utilize group variables in the **Pipeline** (assuming permissions are set properly) I found out *its not* the intended workflow for Azure DevOps to load one group over another with some kind of condition in the **Pipeline**.

So what I did was:

1. For the **Pipeline**, focus all the tasks to generate artifacts that you will utilize in the **Release**. Remember it will run for every branch included in the trigger.
2. Then in the **Release**, choose the artifact and create different stages for each environment, and have those environments linked to the proper variable groups.

This way, the **Pipeline** can be triggered by commits and run for each individual branch and then do the tasks that require the group variables in the **Release** portion that gets triggered when the artifact is created. So in conclusion, I get my condition filtering through the different stages in the **Release** and apply whatever tasks required at that point in the workflow.

I hope this helps someone understand the structure and difference between **pipeline** and **release** and save time on structuring your DevOps Build/Release workflow right the first time :)

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue and this worked for me:

for example, you're trying to retrieve a group variable named `dev-01`

```
    - name: currentStack
      value: ${{ format('$({0}-{1})', variables['env'], variables['location']) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of simple solution is to support these different environments per branch would be by creating a variable group per branch/environment.

[image]

Now using expressions we can obtain required variable group based on branch name.

```
  variables:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
    - group: Prod
  - ${{ if ne(variables['build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
    - group: DEV
```