# Is there a way to parametrize/dynamically set variable group names in Azure DevOps Pipelines YAML?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a nested Azure DevOps YAML pipeline:

```
---
name: Some Release Pipeline

trigger: none

variables:
  - group: "DEV VARIABLE GROUP" # This is the environment variable library

stages:
  - stage: Stage1
    displayName: "Stage 1"
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
      - template: /pipelines/pipeline_templates/sometemplate.yml
```

What I would like to do is reuse this release pipeline for any environment.  Ideally I would set a pipeline variable "group-name" and then assign it to the group.  Something like this:

```
---
name: Some Release Pipeline

trigger: none

variables:
 - group: "$(group-name)" # This is the environment variable library

stages:
 - stage: Stage1
    displayName: "Stage 1"
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
      - template: /pipelines/pipeline_templates/sometemplate.yml
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.  Desperately, I've tried a variety of approaches:

- Using `${{ group-name }}`
- I've tried to pass the group-name as a parameter using:

```
    jobs:
      - template: /pipelines/pipeline_templates/sometemplate.yml
        parameters:
          variablegroup: $(group-name)
```

and then setting it in the sometemplate.yml in the job. eg:

```
jobs:
  - job: Job1
    variables:
      - group: ${{ parameters.variablegroup }}
```

However, this didn't work neither.

- I've tried using [insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#insertion) (`{{ insert }}`) as suggested [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/340).  However, either I don't know how to use insertion properly, or that doesn't work either as I was always encountering some form of validation errors.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59173157/pass-a-variable-group-name-using-rest-api-azure-devops), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52372291/azure-devops-vsts-link-variable-group-through-yaml), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56224798/can-group-name-variable-be-dynamic-in-azure-pipelines), and [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3702) it doesn't seem possible.

I am wondering if anyone has found a solution to this yet (other then doing a really messy workaround of calling the DevOps REST API)?

Answer (score 4):

Your intuition of passing the group name as a parameter to the template was correct. I was able to get this working:

**Template file passing-variable-groups.yml**

```
parameters:
- name: deploymentVariableLibraries
  type: object
  default:
    dev: ''
    qa: ''
    prod: ''

jobs:
- job: TestDev
  variables:
    - group: ${{parameters.deploymentVariableLibraries.dev}}
  steps:
    - script: echo "$(whichEnvironment)"
- job: TestQa
  variables:
    - group: ${{parameters.deploymentVariableLibraries.qa}}
  steps:
    - script: echo "$(whichEnvironment)"
- job: TestProd
  variables:
    - group: ${{parameters.deploymentVariableLibraries.prod}}
  steps:
    - script: echo "$(whichEnvironment)"
```

**Pipeline**

```
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: c4ePipelineExamples-Templates

jobs:
- template: passing-variable-groups.yml@templates
  parameters:
    deploymentVariableLibraries:
      dev: 'test-dev'
      qa: 'test-qa'
      prod: 'test-prod'
```

My output from each job is DEV, QA, PROD respectively (the value of whichEnvironment in each test variable library).

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me without any templates

```
variables:
- group: variables-${{variables['Build.SourceBranchName']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried injecting the variables [mapping as a parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#job-stage-and-step-templates-with-parameters).

> Parameters are not limited to scalar strings. As long as the place where the parameter expands expects a mapping, the parameter can be a mapping. Likewise, sequences can be passed where sequences are expected.

```
# sometemplate.yml
parameters:
  variables: {}

jobs:
- job: build
  variables: ${{ parameters.variables }}
```

```
# somepipeline.yml
name: Some Release Pipeline

trigger: none

stages:
 - stage: Stage1
    displayName: "Stage 1"
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
      - template: sometemplate.yml
        parameters:
          variables: 
            group: "DEV VARIABLE GROUP"
```

I've used parameters to inject task sets as before/after actions to other tasks in a template, but I haven't used it to inject a mapping. I would think the area that this particular implementation would get sticky is in [the need to use `name/value` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?tabs=yaml&%3Bview=azure-devops&view=azure-devops#use-a-variable-group). I imagine if you're passing a group mapping into a job, anything else defining variables would need to use the extended syntax.

> If you use both variables and variable groups, you'll have to use name/value syntax for the individual (non-grouped) variables:

**Also, you may need to be careful as to when you're using runtime `$()` vs "compile" or expansion time `${{ }}` syntax. Working with variables you may want to use expansion time references where possible.**

Comment: Agree with the preference to use compile-time syntax where possible, and runtime where the value can't be known at that point - one of the nice things this does is to allow you to download the expanded YAML and have as many values as possible in place, which simplifies validation and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

played around a bit based on @antonpinchuk answer, and this seemed to do the trick for my scenario:

```yaml
variables:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop') }}:
    - group: vars-dev
  - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}:
    - group: vars-prod
```

The parameter approach also works very well, you could even do a dry approach for your example:

```yaml
jobs:
- ${{ each varGroup in parameters.deploymentVariableLibraries }}:
  - job: ${{ varGroup }}
    variables:
    - group: ${{ varGroup }}
```