# variable template name is dynamic

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to refer to template file as shown below:

```
variables:
  - template: code-quality/code-quality-variables['Build.Repository.Name'].yml
  #- template: code-quality/code-quality.yml
```

How can I access the template file name dynamically based on the repository name?

`variables['Build.Repository.Name']` is taken as-is instead of resolving it dynamically in azure pipeline.

I also tried to do this using a parameter

```
- name: codeQuality
  type: string
  default: concat('code-quality/code-quality', '-', variables['Build.Repository.Name'])
```

**

Also, in parameters is it possible to refer to a dynamic variable name?

```
qualityEnabled: ${{variables.variables['Build.Repository.Name']_allowQuality}}
#qualityEnabled: ${{variables.repositoryname_allowQuality}}
```

I want the variable name `variables['Build.Repository.Name']_allowQuality` to be resolved as respectiverepositoryname_allowQuality

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#format

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts?view=azure-devops

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60159220/is-there-a-way-to-parametrize-dynamically-set-variable-group-names-in-azure-devo

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/notfunction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template name can be dynamic.

```
  - template: code-quality/code-quality-${{variables['Build.Repository.Name']}}.yml
```

If you want a list of values in a variable template then do this way:

```
variables:
  sampleList: |
    some-value
    some-other-value
```

Now you can use `contains` method