# Azure DevOps Pipeline variables format usage

Tags: templates, variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am having an issue with the variables in Azure DevOps pipelines. I can not effectively use them in an if statement or as a placeholder in a value argument.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71874281/variable-template-name-is-dynamic) is a related question but the answer does not work for me.

I have defined a variable like this in the top level pipeline .yml file.

```yaml
variables:
- name: artifact_source
  readonly: true
  value: 'ecu'

- name: artifact_getter
  readonly: true
  value: 'get_artifacts_ecu.yaml'
```

And in a lower level template file i want to use them like this:

```yaml
    # Get binaries
    - template: $(artifact_getter)
      parameters:
        variant: ${{ parameters.variant }}
```

Gives me this error: File /.azuredevops/template/$(artifact_getter) not found in repository.

or

```yaml
jobs:
  - job: ${{ parameters.variant }}
    pool: ${{ parameters.pool }}
    steps:

    # Clean checkout
    - checkout: self
      clean: true

    # Get binaries
    - ${{ if eq( $(artifact_source), 'ecu') }}:
      - template: get_artifacts_ecu.yml
        parameters:
          variant: ${{ parameters.variant }}
```

This gives an error: Unrecognized value: '$'. Located at position 5 within expression: eq( $(artifact_source), 'ecu'). For more help, refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=842996

I am wondering about what format i should use to get the value of the variable here. I see different forms how to reference variables:

```yaml
${{ variables.artifact_source }}
$[variables.var]
$env:artifact_source
$(artifact_source)  # only one working for variables
```

Also documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax). But i can only get `$(name)` to work, but not in my case.

How can i use variables to switch to a different template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Expressions document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#variables), it mentions as part of an expression, you may access variables using one of two syntaxes:

- Index syntax: `variables['MyVar']`
- Property dereference syntax:   `variables.MyVar`

So, you can use `eq(variables['artifact_source'], 'ecu')` or `eq(variables.artifact_source, 'ecu')` here.

```
# Get binaries
- ${{ if eq(variables['artifact_source'], 'ecu') }}:
  - template: get_artifacts_ecu.yml
    parameters:
      variant: ${{ parameters.variant }}
```

or

```
# Get binaries
- ${{ if eq(variables.artifact_source, 'ecu') }}:
  - template: get_artifacts_ecu.yml
    parameters:
      variant: ${{ parameters.variant }}
```

Comment: Thank you for clairifying, I  think i got messed up with the various formats. I thought i had tried every variant, but it works now. Thanks a lot!